# Why does TFS Build not recognize xcopy as a command?

Tags: tfsbuild, xcopy

I am using TFS 2008 and within my `TFSBuild.proj` file I have a target that calls `xcopy` to copy the build to the production location. However, I am receiving the following error when running the build:

> Task "Exec" Command:  xcopy "\test\TFSBuilds\Online System V2 Build to NETPUB_20100430.2\Debug_PublishedWebsites\IPAMIntranet" "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\IPAMOnlineSystem\IPAMIntranet\IPAMIntranet" /E
>
> Parse Error 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\IPAMOnlineSystem\IPAMIntranet\IPAMIntranet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> '" /E ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The following is my code line for the xcopy:

```
<Target Name="AfterDropBuild">
  <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Debug\_PublishedWebsites\IPAMIntranet&quot; &quot;$(RemoteDeploySitePath)&quot; /E " /> 
</Target>
```

I have even tried single quotes around the file locations and actual double quotes insteand of the " symbols. Why is this happening, can anyone decipher this for me and help me correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have a newline in your definition of RemoteDeploySitePath?

For example, if you do this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RemoteDeploySitePath>
    C:\\Inetpub\wwwroot\IPAMOnlineSystem\IPAMIntranet\IPAMIntranet
  </RemoteDeploySitePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

vs this (still inside a PropertyGroup element of course):

```
<RemoteDeploySitePath>C:\\Inetpub\wwwroot\IPAMOnlineSystem\IPAMIntranet\IPAMIntranet</RemoteDeploySitePath>
```

The resulting property in the first case will include the newlines.

What does your definition of RemoteDeploySitePath look like?

Comment: I had the first case you stated, however I took that definition out and placed the destination directly into the command and it is just hanging now.

Comment: Could you add some debug <Message... tasks and post back with the commands and arguments?